# Сlassification using convolutional layers

Tags: convolution

I have a simple neural network of 2 layers, recognizing 10 classes:

```
self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(14 * 14 * 32, 10)
```

How can a classification be made using the convolutional layer in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You need `Dense()` layers after convolution / pooling layers. Conv and max-pool are meant to process pixel data in a format that can be later received from dense layers.
It's the `Dense()` output layer that, using a `softmax` activation, can technically perform the classification (by returning a one-hot encoded vector).

Comment: But Dense and Linear are one and the same. I want to know if there is a way to classify an object other than using a fully connected layer?

Comment: Dense layers are not necessarily "linear", that depends on your choice of activation functions. However, I don't think it's possible to classify observations without Dense layers.

Comment: See "fully convolutional network"